# How do I go about implementing sprite masking?

Tags: directx, sprite, masking, orthographic

Using DirectX I'm rendering textured polygons (orthographically) so they act as HUD sprites. Now I'm not sure how would I go about implementing sprite masking in this sytem?

So basically say I have a sprite, how can I make it render only in a given portion of the screen which I define? And if a part of it moves outside this portion of the screen you don't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scissor Test.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee422196(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for what is called a viewport. considering you did not specify which DirectX and which language you're using, I'll have to point to the [DirectX9 spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee421783%28VS.85%29.aspx)